# How can I check if object exists in array of objects and update quantity?

Tags: javascript

I have an array `objArray`. I want to make a function so that it will check if there is another object with the same `name` key. If it exists, it will add +1 in the `qty` key. If the object doesn't exist, it will push the new object to the array.

```js
var objArray = [
  {"name":"bike","color":"blue","qty":2},
  {"name":"boat","color":"pink", "qty":1},
];

var carObj = {"name":"car","color":"red","qty":1};
var bikeObj = {"name":"bike","color":"blue","qty":1};
  
function checkAndAdd (obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
      if (objArray[i].name === obj.name) {
          objArray[i].qty++;
          break;
      }
      else {
          objArray.push(obj);
      }
    };
}

checkAndAdd(carObj);

console.log(objArray);

checkAndAdd(bikeObj);

console.log(objArray);
```

After `checkAndAdd(carObj);`

```
console.log(objArray);
```

Should give

```
[
  {"name":"car","color":"red", "qty":1},
  {"name":"bike","color":"blue","qty":2},
  {"name":"boat","color":"pink", "qty":1},
]
```

And fter `checkAndAdd(bikeObj);`

```
console.log(objArray);
```

Should give

```
[
  {"name":"car","color":"red", "qty":1},
  {"name":"bike","color":"blue","qty":3},
  {"name":"boat","color":"pink", "qty":1},
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @D.Pardal it actually took me a few minutes to undesrstand that as well, as OP didn't make it clear. It seems that when a car is pushed, the quantity ends up being `2` instead of `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check all objects and exit the function if one item is found for incrementing the quantity.

If not found push the object.

```js
var objArray = [{ name: "bike", color: "blue", qty: 2 }, { name: "boat", color: "pink", qty: 1 }],
    carObj = { name: "car", color: "red", qty: 1 },
    bikeObj = { name: "bike", color: "blue", qty: 1 };
  
function checkAndAdd (obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        if (objArray[i].name === obj.name) {
            objArray[i].qty++;
            return;                             // exit loop and function
        }
    }
    objArray.push(obj);
}

checkAndAdd(carObj);
console.log(objArray);

checkAndAdd(bikeObj);
console.log(objArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That was it! I will mark this as correct as it is the most straightforward one for my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `find` to search for the object property.

Using `Object.assign` before pushing the object will clone the object and will not change the original object when you change the `qty` (If you add more object with the same name.)

```js
var objArray = [
    {"name":"bike","color":"blue","qty":2},
    {"name":"boat","color":"pink", "qty":1},
];

var carObj = {"name":"car","color":"red","qty":1};
var bikeObj = {"name":"bike","color":"blue","qty":1};

function checkAndAdd(obj) {
  let o = objArray.find(o => o.name === obj.name);  //Find if name exist

  if (!o) objArray.push(Object.assign({},obj));     //If not exist, push. 
  else o.qty += obj.qty;                            //If exist, add the qty
}

checkAndAdd(carObj);
console.log(objArray);

checkAndAdd(bikeObj);
console.log(objArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're `push()`ing inside the loop, instead of returning immediately once found and only call `push()` outside the loop.

A cleaner approach would be:

```
function checkAndAdd(obj) {
    var matchingObj = objArray.find(o => o.name === obj.name);

    if (matchingObj)
        matchingObj.qty++;
    else
        objArray.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**findIndex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find in objArray if the object exist.If it does then update the object else push the new object

```js
var objArray = [{
    "name": "bike",
    "color": "blue",
    "qty": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "boat",
    "color": "pink",
    "qty": 1
  },
];

var carObj = {
  "name": "car",
  "color": "red",
  "qty": 1
};
var bikeObj = {
  "name": "bike",
  "color": "blue",
  "qty": 1
};

function checkAndAdd(obj) {
  var x = objArray.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.name === obj.name;

  });
  if (x === -1) {
    objArray.push(obj)
  } else {
    objArray[x].qty = objArray[x].qty + obj.qty
  }
}

checkAndAdd(carObj);
checkAndAdd(bikeObj);
console.log(objArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough:

```
function checkAndAdd(obj) {
for (var i=0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
    if (objArray[i]name === obj.name) {
        objArray[i].qty++;
        return
    }
}
objArray.push(obj)
}
```

### Explanation:

Your function was pushing each time the object name didn't match. Instead, when this function a matching name, it incrementes the `qty` and stops and then if the loops ends without any match, it pushes the `obj`.